# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed when hibernate creates tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

The idea is that my suppliers can have several couples of VCurrency and Currency.

For example, SupplierA can have these couples of VCurrency and Currency:

- VC1 - RC1
- VC1 - RC2
- VC2 - RC1
- VC3 - RC2
- VC3 - RC3

Here is my Supplier class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idSupplier;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
    private List<SupplierCurrency> availableCurrencies;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Here is my VCurrency class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("V")
public class VCurrency extends Currency {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vCurrency")
    private List<SupplierCurrency> suppliers;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Here is my Currency class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="currencyType",
    discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Currency {

    @Id
    private String symbol;

    private String name;
```

And to merge this all, here is my SupplierCurrency class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier_currency")
public class SupplierCurrency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idSupplierCurrency;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="supplier")
    private Fournisseur supplier;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="v_currency")
    private VCurrency vCurrency;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="currency")
    private Currency Currency;

}
```

But when I start my Spring App, I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table supplier_currency add constraint FKt2waed3bwbw43k9xkiqebjxjh foreign key (id_supplier_currency) references supplier_currency (id_supplier_currency)]
java.sql.SQLException: Error on rename of '.\#sql-1b0c_1a9' to '.\supplier_currency' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

It's like Hibernate tries to link supplier_currency to itself.

Comment: I answer myself: VCurrency needs a OneToMany instead of ManyToOne